# How to decrease the height of BannerAd of AdMob in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob, banner-ads

[image]I've implemented [firebase_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) package on my app. When I display ad at the bottom of the screen it takes huge space (big height) which I have not seen in any other app. How can I decrease the height of that `BannerAd` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the official [DOCS](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#limitations):

> **Limitations**
>
> This plugin currently has some limitations:
>
> - Banner ads cannot be animated into view.
> - **It's not possible to specify a banner ad's size.**
> - There's no support for native ads.
> - The existing tests are fairly rudimentary.
> - There is no API doc.
> - The example should demonstrate how to show gate a route push with an interstitial ad

Answer (score 1):

If you used the smart banner it adjusts the height according to device height,
so if you want a small banner do not use smartBanner, use banner instead.

Banner has a fixed height of 50.

size: AdSize.banner

```
  BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
      // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event is $event");
      },
    );
```